# How to send a zip file in Android without saving it first?

Tags: android, zip

I have this code to compress in zip format some files:

```
 public int zip(List<String> _files, String zipFileName) {
        try {
            BufferedInputStream origin = null;
            FileOutputStream dest = new FileOutputStream(zipFileName);
            ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(
                    dest));
            byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER];

            for (int i = 0; i < _files.size(); i++) {
                Log.v("Compress", "Adding: " + _files.get(i));
                FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(_files.get(i));
                origin = new BufferedInputStream(fi, BUFFER);

                ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(_files.get(i).substring(_files.get(i).lastIndexOf(File.separator) + 1));
                out.putNextEntry(entry);
                int count;

                while ((count = origin.read(data, 0, BUFFER)) != -1) {
                    out.write(data, 0, count);
                }
                origin.close();
            }

            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 1;
    }
```

I would like to get the **ZipOutPutStream** and send it through Intent or some other way, not saving it like in:

```
while ((count = origin.read(data, 0, BUFFER)) != -1) {
                    out.write(data, 0, count);
                }
```

Is there a way to do it? Currently I just can send the zip using its saved name as a String.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way.  Intents are limited to 2 MB, so it could only hold a very small zipfile.  And the receivers aren't expecting raw data.  You also can't send objects (like a ZipOutputStream) because Intents only send the serialized version of its extras, as the receiver may not be in the same process.

Comment: The trick is you'd need to delete it after the receiver is done with it.  So it may be worth either writing it in your cache files and letting Android do that for you, or doing it at some point in the future.

Comment: Humm... I was not thinking about writing it in the cache. How can I do that?

Comment: For the zip filename, make it relative to the cache directory getCacheDir().